# How to select the anchor tag which is inside the li in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Below is my code. I want to click the anchor tag `<a>`, which is inside the `<li>`. I have tried to get the value using `By.tagName("//li/a")`. I didn't get any data.

There are many lists with `class="dropdown-menu"` in my HTML. I should be able to select a single list from which to click the drop down values.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="position: static; margin-bottom: 5px; *width: 50px;border-style: none;min-width: 45px;box-shadow: 0 0px;text-align: center;" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" role="menu">
  <li><a class="dropdown-add" style="cursor: pointer;">1</a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-add" style="cursor: pointer;">2</a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-add" style="cursor: pointer;">3</a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-add" style="cursor: pointer;">4</a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-add" style="cursor: pointer;">5</a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-add" style="cursor: pointer;">6</a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-add" style="cursor: pointer;">7</a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-add" style="cursor: pointer;">8</a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-add" style="cursor: pointer;">9</a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-add" style="cursor: pointer;">10</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Show what you tried. What do you mean "between the anchor tag"? There are no other elements between the anchor tags.

Comment: What element between the anchor tag? Did you just mean the anchors text ?

Comment: I have tried the following code to click the element:List<WebElement> drop = button.findElements(By.tagName("//li/a"));
   for(int i=1; i<drop.size(); i++){
    if(!(drop.get(i).getText().isEmpty())){
    drop.get(3).click();} Here i have tried to click the value 3 from the drop down.

Comment: Please update the code into your question, it's far easier to read from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy to get list of all anchors, just use CSS Selectors

```
List<WebElement> anchors = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul li a"));
```

Then choose whatever anchor you want to click at, let's say

```
anchors.findElement(By.linkText("10")).click();
```

Answer (score -1):

First get the NodeList of the anchors:

```
var res = document.querySelectorAll('ul.dropdown-menu li a.dropdown-add');
```

Then force a `click` on the 3rd, if it's not empty:

```
if(res[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue.length) { res[2].click() };
```

Comment: OP mistagged the question, this isn't about JavaScript.