# Selenium - Select Item From List By The ul li Value Text

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I've got the following HTML

```
<div id="colLeft_OrderGroups" class="GroupList GroupList_Left">
            <div class="SelectList" style="height:516px;">
                <div class="DialogSubtitle">Available groups</div>
                <ul class="ui-selectable" id="grdAvailableGroups" style="width:100%; margin-right:2px">
                <li value="10929">AppraisersGroupTest</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How do I select the option based off the "AppraisersGroupTest" text?

There will be multiple values in the list soon, so I need to be able to specify the text.

I have tried the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20900854/how-to-select-the-anchor-tag-which-is-inside-the-li-in-selenium-webdriver), but I'm getting syntax errors I cannot resolve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your HTML, I'm going to assume that the `value` of the desired `LI` is going to always be "10929" for your desired "AppraisersGroupTest." With that info, you can use the code below.

```
String value = "10929";
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("grdAvailableGroups"));
dropdown.click(); // assuming you have to click the "dropdown" to open it
dropdown.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[value=" + value + "]")).click();
```

If it turns out that is not a good assumption, you can use the code below to search for the desired text and click the element.

```
String searchText = "AppraisersGroupTest";
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("grdAvailableGroups"));
dropdown.click(); // assuming you have to click the "dropdown" to open it
List<WebElement> options = dropdown.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
for (WebElement option : options)
{
    if (option.getText().equals(searchText))
    {
        option.click(); // click the desired option
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not believe the value will always be the same as the code will have to work on numerous environments and the setup will more than likely generate different values, so I will try the latter suggestion first thing in the morning. That looks like it is exactly what I need. Thank you for your help, sir.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using one liner `xPath` as below :-

```
String text = "AppraisersGroupTest";
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'colLeft_OrderGroups']/descendant::li[text() = '" + text + "']"));
el.click();
```

Hope it will help you...:)

Comment: I tried this and it does work perfectly fine. If I could mark 2 answers, I would because I like how little code is used here.

Comment: @DustinN. it's all depends on you here only one answer could be acceptable per question but you should accept possible best answer..:)

Answer (score 0):

'For anyone who may need it

Sub Memlogin()

```
'Login Members Profile
Dim IE As New selenium.WebDriver
Set IE = New ChromeDriver

With IE
        .Get "Your URL"

        .FindElementByName("Uni_user_id").SendKeys ("Your User ID")

        .FindElementByName("password").SendKeys ("Your Password")

        .FindElementById("Uni_login_button").Click

        'Select Profile Section
        .Get "Secondary URL if Needed"
 
        .Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
        
End With

'Select Desired Tab
Dim MTab, Tabs, User As selenium.WebElement
Set MTab = IE.FindElementByTag("ul")
Set Tabs = IE.FindElementByClass("li class-name ")
Set User = IE.FindElementByXPath("//a[text()=""li innerText""]")


IE.Actions.MoveToElement(User).Click(User).Perform

IE.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:20")
```

End Sub

1. List item

Comment: It logins a website, selects a webpage tab that may otherwise be hard or seem impossible to select via traditional functions

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).