# How to choose a item from a list in a multi_select in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

what i have tried:

```
Select listbox = new Select(
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='multiselect_categories']"))
);
listbox.selectByValue("ATM");
```

Html code when some option choose:

```
<input name="multiselect_categories" id="multiselect_categories" 
       type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Select option" 
       tabindex="0" class="multiselect__input" style="display: none;">

<div class="multiselect__tags">
  <div class="multiselect__tags-wrap" style="">
    <span class="multiselect__tag">
      <span>Actions and Practices</span>
      <i aria-hidden="true" tabindex="1" class="multiselect__tag-icon"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="multiselect__tag">
      <span>Air Carrier Services and Safety Oversight</span>
      <i aria-hidden="true" tabindex="1" class="multiselect__tag-icon"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="multiselect__spinner" style="display: none;"></div>
  <input name="multiselect_categories" id="multiselect_categories" 
         type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Select option" 
         tabindex="0" class="multiselect__input" 
         style="width: 0px; position: absolute; padding: 0px; display: none;">  
</div>

<div class="multiselect__content-wrapper" style="max-height: 291.375px; display: none;">
  <ul class="multiselect__content" style="display: inline-block;">
    <li class="multiselect__element">
      <span data-select="Press enter to select" data-selected="Selected" 
            data-deselect="Press enter to remove" class="multiselect__option">
        <span>ATM</span>
      </span> 
    </li>
    <li class="multiselect__element">
      <span data-select="Press enter to select" data-selected="Selected" 
            data-deselect="Press enter to remove" class="multiselect__option 
            multiselect__option--selected">
        <span>Actions and Practices</span>
      </span> 
    </li>
    <li class="multiselect__element">
      <span data-select="Press enter to select" data-selected="Selected" 
            data-deselect="Press enter to remove" class="multiselect__option 
            multiselect__option--selected">
        <span>Air Carrier Services and Safety Oversight</span>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CODE that failed when adding to selenium code when adding to testng:

```
@Test(description = "Test5")
public void chooseCatagory(String... catagories) {
    for(String catagory: catagories) {
        // input catagory in text box which display placeholder `Select option`
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.multiselect__tags #multiselect_categories"))
            .sendKeys(catagory);
        // find the item from auto-suggest list
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.multiselect__tags + div > ul"))
            .findElement(By.xpath("./li//span[text()='"+catagory+"']"))
            .click();
    }
}
chooseCatagory("ATM", "Airports");
```

Error from the above code:
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [chooseCatagory] with [class [Ljava.lang.String;].
For more information on native dependency injection please refer to http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection
org.testng.TestNGException:

HTML when there is nothing chosen:

```
<input name="multiselect_categories" id="multiselect_categories" 

type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Select option" tabindex="0" class="multiselect__input" style="display: none;">
<span><span class="multiselect__single">
            Select option
          </span></span>
```

what the list contains:
ATM,Action, refer to screenshot

Comment: html code: <input name="multiselect_categories" id="multiselect_categories" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Select option" tabindex="0" class="multiselect__input" style="width: 0px; position: absolute; padding: 0px; display: none;">

Comment: html code: <span class="multiselect__tag"><span>ATM</span> <i aria-hidden="true" tabindex="1" class="multiselect__tag-icon"></i></span>

Comment: You can not use select here as it is not select tag. try with element click without select class

Comment: there is still a list of data to select from, i just took the top item, how would the click then work?

Comment: Pleas give a screeshot of your MultipleSelect list

Comment: @yong, i dont have rights to send screenshot

Comment: but it looks like this: ATM       (press enter to select )                                      Action and practices             (press enter to select)

Comment: its a list of options then next to each option there is that text saying "press enter to select"

Comment: Typically you click it once to open the dropdown and then click the desired element from the dropdown. You treat it like any other HTML on the page because it's not a `SELECT` element so you can't use `Select()`.

Comment: @JeffC how would i then select the text? because there is a list of various options to choose from?

Comment: Please edit your question and describe what you are trying to accomplish **in words** because right now it's unclear. Are you trying to click on an option or "select the text"? Now that you know that `Select()` is not an option here, please update your code to current attempts.

Comment: @yong i have added a picture

Comment: @yong i have added images of the html code, when items are the list. i cant give anymore information as its restricted build.

Comment: @yong i have added the entire html code

Comment: Go through this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212644/selenium-select-item-from-list-by-the-ul-li-value-text

Comment: **Go through this link** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212644/selenium-select-item-from-list-by-the-ul-li-value-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Test(description = "Test5")
public test_chooseCatagory() {
    chooseCatagory("ATM", "Airports");
}

private void chooseCatagory(String... catagories) {
    for(String catagory: catagories) {
        // click the down arrow at right to make the filter text box and
        // all option list display
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.multiselect__select"))
          .click();

        // input catagory into text box to filter matched options
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".multiselect__tags #multiselect_categories"))
          .sendKeys(catagory);

        // click the option from filtered option list 
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".multiselect__content-wrapper > ul"))
          .findElement(By.xpath("./li//span[text()='"+catagory+"']"))
          .click();

        // sleep 2 seconds before next choosing
        try {
         Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        } 
    } 
}
```